# How can I have a string and an int in a swift dictionary that is decoded from json

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to make a trivia app but am getting stuck on parsing the json received. I also would like to know how I can use the data with swift UI

I have tried to make a object for it to be stored but can't seem to get it.

Here is the JSON I receive

```
{"response_code":0,"results":[{"category":"Entertainment: Film","type":"multiple","difficulty":"medium","question":"In Mulan (1998), who is the leader of the Huns?","correct_answer":"Shan Yu","incorrect_answers":["Chien-Po","Li Shang","Fa Zhou"]}]}
```

Their also can be many dictionaries in the results

Here is what I am using to get and decode data

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class NetworkingManager :ObservableObject {
    init(amount:Int) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=\(String(amount))") else {return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data,_,_) in
            guard let data = data else{return }
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            let question =  try! decoder.decode(TriviaQuestion.self, from: data)
            print(question.responseCode)
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Here is my struct

```
struct TriviaQuestion : Codable{
    var responseCode:Int
    var results:Array<Dictionary<String,String>>

}
```

in the try statement it won't let me create the TriviaQuestion object because it has a list in the incorect_answers key. I also do not know if I am putting the Observable object in the correct format. Here is the actual error.

> Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "results", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), _JSONKey(stringValue: "incorrect_answers", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil)): file /Users/shorya/Desktop/Quick Trivia/Quick Trivia/NetworkingManager.swift, line 21
>   2019-09-02 10:59:28.608392-0400 Quick Trivia[15807:307693] Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "results", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), _JSONKey(stringValue: "incorrect_answers", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil)): file /Users/shorya/Desktop/Quick Trivia/Quick Trivia/NetworkingManager.swift, line 21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`incorrectAnswers` is an array not a string , You need

```
// MARK: - Empty
struct TriviaQuestion: Codable {
    let responseCode: Int
    let results: [Result] 
}

// MARK: - Result
struct Result: Codable {
    let category, type, difficulty, question: String
    let correctAnswer: String
    let incorrectAnswers: [String] 
}
```

Also its safe to

```
 do { 
     let decoder = JSONDecoder() 
     decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
     let question =  try decoder.decode(TriviaQuestion.self, from: data)
  }
  catch {
     print(error)
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, I also have one more question. How can I access this data from a swift UI view. Sorry I am a beginner